# strpos() is not working on file_get_contents() result as its parameter

Tags: php

I am currently working on a solution that gets part of specific string on a web page.

But it seems that **strpos()** function is not working when I put the **file_get_contents()** result as its parameter.

```
$link = "http://cavwdb01/dev_maximaps/index.php?id=208105477856";
$source = file_get_contents($link);
$string = htmlentities($source);


$first = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
$second = '</option><option value="3">';
echo "<br><br>";

echo $open = stripos($string, $first);

echo $close = strpos($string, $second);
echo "<br><br>";
```

but when I copy the result and put it in a variable , it works perfectly.

```
$string = 'file get content result here .......';

$first = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
$second = '</option><option value="3">';
echo "<br><br>";
echo $open = stripos($string, $first);
echo $close = strpos($string, $second);
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Assy Vendor: <br>";
echo $assyVendor = substr($string, 0, 10);
```

any idea, what is the difference between directly putting the **file_get_content()** result as parameter with the variable with the same content?

Comment: `htmlentities()` is encoding characters like `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which is why strpos is not finding those strings.

Comment: How about **htmlentities()** when using file_get_contents() directly?

Comment: @tshimkus: It works.. Thank you so much. This solve my problem.

Comment: Use `$source` as the string in `stripos()` and `strpos()` functions OR modify the search strings to be encoded as they would be if you use an encoding function.

Comment: @tshimkus, i use `$source` as parameter, and I got the position of the `$first`. however, dor the second string, I cna't fine it. considering that it's just the same fucntion i use the only changes was the parameter.

Comment: @Chods, the first instance is `stripos()`, which is case insensitive, while the second instance you use the case sensitive `strpos()`. Not sure if casing comes into play here but these two functions are slightly different.